# Magento 2 not reading env.php

Tags: magento2.2

After a migration, The website is loading fine. BUT...

If I try to do certain things that require access to the database (ie: add/remove a product image), I get this message:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 TRIGGER command denied to user 'heav_admin'@'localhost' for table...

Magento is trying to use the old database username? (* without the "en"

The env.php file has the correct user in it "heaven_admin'  ( *with the 'en"

I can't find anywhere else it's stored in! I have tried:

- php bin/magento setup:config:set --db-user heaven_admin
- I can't make a new user with that prefix
- deleting var/static folders and regenerating
- banging my head on keyboard

Does anyone have an idea where magento is getting that old username from?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there was a MYSQL trigger added to a certain action. And the trigger is using the old DB user.

It might be added via PHP, so you could check all custom modules for the string "trigger" - this might help you find the source.

Also you should log into phpmyadmin and check if there are any triggers on the database.

You can check with a command like this:

```
show triggers from db_name
```

There might be a trigger with old DB user permissions.

**EDIT**

To remove the trigger just use this command:

```
drop trigger db_name.trigger_name
```

But you should make sure that you really want to remove the trigger. It might be used for something that you need, but don't know about.

Maybe you should just update the permissions to the new db_user.

Comment: Awsome Lez! I can see them listed with this command in phpMyAdmin... Now I just have to figure out how to change/remove them :)

Comment: Well... this triggers tab seems to be a good place to start! lol

Comment: @JeffKeller check my edit on how to remove the trigger.

Comment: You saved me lots of headaches that the hosting caused by changing the account name. I was able to just edit the triggers with the correct user name. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!